# Why Enumerator MoveNext() returns 0

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerator

Why next code generates loop hangs?

```cs
var x = new
{
    Items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }.GetEnumerator()
};

while (x.Items.MoveNext())
   Console.WriteLine(x.Items.Current);
```

If I get enumerator after x initialization, than everything works fine:

```cs
var x = new
{
    Items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
};

var enumerator = x.Items.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
   Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
```

Tried to decompile both code blocks, but don't understand the reason:

```cs
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
intList.Add(1);
intList.Add(2);
intList.Add(3);
var data1 = new \u003C\u003Ef__AnonymousType0<List<int>.Enumerator>(intList.GetEnumerator());
while (true)
{
   List<int>.Enumerator items = data1.Items;
   if (items.MoveNext())
   {
     items = data1.Items;
     Console.WriteLine(items.Current);
   }
   else
     break;
}
List<int> Items = new List<int>();
Items.Add(1);
Items.Add(2);
Items.Add(3);
var data2 = new \u003C\u003Ef__AnonymousType0<List<int>>(Items);
List<int>.Enumerator enumerator = data2.Items.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
   Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
```

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/07/27/iterate-damn-you/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because List's enumerator is a struct. In your first example, you're creating an enumerator object (somewhere, probably heap, doesn't matter) and every time you access it with `.Items` the enumerator gets copied onto the stack in your executing function. `MoveNext` mutates it and then the copied enumerator gets discarded. If it were a class, only the reference would be copied/discarded and the actual data modified but since it's a struct, you didn't modify the enumerator in `var x { ... }` at all. `Enumerator.Current` returns 0 because `default(int)` is zero but an exception would be possible, too.

In your second example you're creating a slot for the enumerator on the stack with `var enumerator = x.Items.GetEnumerator();` and that slot gets accessed repeadedly without copies.